# Filling following Six cells based on the letter entered in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Naso.png)I have a sheet where I have to enter the letter combinations that shows the time taken by the product on different work stations. For example, if a products "X" arrives in the company, it goes through inspection for 1 week then it goes to process department for two weeks, and then finally to packaging department for 1 week for packaging. I have a list where all the products are listed with their arriving date. I have created different legend for the departments:

```
Inspection = "I"
Process Department = "PD"
Packaging = "P"
```

All the products are listed with their arriving date. So When I write in front of a product the letter "I", the following two cells should automatically get filled with "PD" and the third cell should be filled with "P". To show when the product will be ready to dispatch.

I have attached a screenshot of the excel I am working on. The Cell-Range to enter the first letter "I" is dynamic. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards
Prem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Naso.png)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you tried. You have not included the screenshot/image.

Comment: 'I have attached a screenshot of the excel I am working on. ' The screenshot is missing

Comment: You can try to edit the post and upload the screenshot again.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Sorry for the delay